# Issue with importing SeleniumLibrary into Robotframework

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, robotframework

I started learn Robotframework. Installed Python, pip and all necessary libraries (on Win10x64). I wrote some simple script just for testing:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test title "Amazon"
    Open Browser    http://www.amazon.com chrome
```

But when I trying to run it I receive an error:

```
# robot e:\Test\dummy\test.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'e:\Test\dummy\test.robot': Importing test library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0a1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from SeleniumLibrary.base import DynamicCore
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\base\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .context import ContextAware
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\base\context.py", line 17, in <module>
    from SeleniumLibrary.utils import escape_xpath_value
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\utils\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .seleniumversion import SELENIUM_VERSION
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\utils\seleniumversion.py", line 23, in <module>

    major, minor, micro = int(major), int(minor), int(micro)
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\robot.exe
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python36.zip
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\DLLs
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-4.0.0a1-py3.6.egg
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
  c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Test title "Amazon"                                                   | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

PATH is OK, all necessary lib is installed. Python ver is 3.6.4

```
# pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.8.0
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
decorator==4.4.0
docutils==0.14
idna==2.6
psutil==5.4.3
pypiwin32==220
requests==2.18.4
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
selenium==4.0.0a1
soupsieve==1.9.2
tqdm==4.32.2
urllib3==1.22
webdrivermanager==0.7.4
```

Can someone explain me where is problem? 3 hours in Google does not helped

Comment: try to import Selenium2Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the selenium version does not match the one required by your robotframework-seleniumlibrary.

```
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
selenium==4.0.0a1
```

You should either install the 4.0 robotframework-seleniumlibrary, which is just an alpha version.

Or best would be to install the `selenium 3.141.0` for your `robotframework-seleniumlibrary  3.3.1`.

```
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
selenium==3.141.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration worked :

*Python Version on Windows 10 :*

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

*SeleniumLibrary Version :*

```
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0 
selenium (3.141.0)
```